# How to find height of a section of the page below a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

Suppose I've the following HTML page:

```
<body>
 <div id="top" style="height: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

How do I find what the height of the page below the `div#top` is and assign it to a variable in JavaScript (jQuery is allowed)?

What I mean is the following:

```
<body>
.-------------------------------. ^
| <div id="top">...</div>       | | 100 px
|-------------------------------| v
|                         ^     | ^
|                         |     | | 
|    How do I find        |     | | rest of the page 
|    this height:         |     | | (nothing here, it's empty)
|                         |     | |
|                         |     | | 
|                         |     | |
|                         |     | |
|                         v     | v
'-------------------------------'
</body>
```

For example, if the visible part of browser window height is 1000px, then I'm looking for answer 900px. If the window height is 777px, then I'm looking for answer 677px. Etc.

Comment: `var height = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("elementId")).height;`

Comment: @akinuri but there is no element *below* div#top...

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamically *find* the height in CSS, but you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to calculate the remaining height.

In this case, `height: calc(100% - 100px)` would work.

You can also use viewport-relative units - `height: calc(100vh - 100px)`.

---

If you want to dynamically find the amount of space *below* an element, just subtract the height of the viewport from the position of the bottom of the element.

Pure JavaScript: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/jt7vg3rj/)

```
var element = document.querySelector('#target'),
    remainingHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight - element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

alert(remainingHeight); // Height below element
```

Equivalent version with increased readability:

```
var element = document.querySelector('#target'),
    elementBottom = element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
    viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
    remainingHeight = viewportHeight - elementBottom;

alert(remainingHeight); // Height below element
```

---

jQuery alternative: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/muojpajL/)

```
var $element = $('#target'),
    remainingHeight = $(window).height() - ($element.position().top + $element.outerHeight(true));

alert(remainingHeight); // Height below element
```

Equivalent version with increased readability:

```
var $element = $('#target'),
    elementBottom = $element.position().top + $element.outerHeight(true),
    viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
    remainingHeight = viewportHeight - elementBottom;

alert(remainingHeight); // Height below element
```

---

Just take the box-model into consideration with both of these solutions, and adjust accordingly. The JavaScript method above doesn't take the element's margin into consideration; whereas the jQuery solution *does*. You haven't made it clear which you want.

Comment: Very nice. Follow up question - how do I assign this value to a JavaScript variable? I need this in my JS code. Sorry for being non specific. I'll update the question. (jQuery is allowed)

Comment: Theeeeeeeenks. I'll try this. :)

Comment: Just tried it - it worked! Jquery is always good. I'm using Jquery in all my project. :) No margin problem and works in IE8 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is self-explanatory. Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gsy961w7/2/). Resize the frame height to see the change in height.

```js
var topElement   = document.getElementById("top");
var topElementHeight     = parseInt(getComputedStyle(topElement).height, 10);
var windowHeight  = window.innerHeight;
var bodyMargin   = parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.body).margin, 10);
var availableHeight  = windowHeight - topElementHeight - bodyMargin;
topElement.innerText     = availableHeight;
```

```css
#top {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
```

Comment: Thenks, but what is `- 8` for on the fourth line?

Comment: @bodacydo By default, `body` element has a margin of `8px`. In the example I didn't override that margin. If you override body margin with `body { margin: 0; }` you don't have to subtract 8.

Comment: Could you update your code to account for margin automatically? So I don't have to find if it's 0 or 8 (or some other value). I'm making a JS library so it can run in any browser with any margin :(

Comment: @bodacydo Done. Updated the fiddle and code in the answer. If `body` has a margin, or not,  `bodyMargin` will be set to that value.

Comment: Yo thanks man! I will credit u in my library. :) It's called WindowSizeComputing.js :)

Comment: @bodacydo Haha. Alright. Drop the link in here when it's done. I'll check it out.